# Adding a polymorphic relationship to a mysql view model?

Tags: laravel

On a `book` and a `movie` model, I define a polymorphic relationship to comments:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

This all works as expected.

I also have a MySQL view defined, which is a union between `book` and `movie`, this is called `feed`.

I have a subsequent `feed` model to access this unioned view.

My question is, how can I add the above polymorphic relationship to my `feed` model?

By just adding the above relationship definition to the `feed` model, it looks for the type `feed` in the polymorphic relationship on `commentable_type` on the `comments` table, but yet I am trying to get it for whichever type the row is `book` or `movie`.

In the union `feed` table I have defined what each row type is... `book` or `movie`...

```
id | title   | type
1. | book a  | book
2. | movie a | movie
```

I think I somehow need to get the row type information in the relationship, is this possible...

```
public function comments()
{
    $model = resolve(whatever type is passed from the row performing the relationship);
    $model->morphMany('App\Models\Comment', 'commentable');
}
```

Comment: I think you should not be doing this at the database level if you want Laravel to work with it like a normal model. Just fetch the books and movies separately and return a merged collection.

Comment: @miken32 a merged collection would not allow for cursor based navigation.